# In App Inventor, how to share a TinyDB between screens?

Tags: app-inventor, tinydb

I added the component `TinyDB1` to Screen1.

Then I went to Screen2 and tried to add the same database as a component, but it's not there in the palette (left hand side screen). It's also not recognized in the call block I added

I would like a common `TinyDB` as a way to transfer data between screens ...

Answer (score 0):

In the designer of Screen2 you first have to drag a `TinyDB` component from the storage drawer into the working area, see also the [TinyDB tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/stevozip/home/AI2/tinydb) by Stephen.

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the [Top 5 Tips: How to learn App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)